# Stash and Unstash in Teamcity

Tags: teamcity, snapshot

In Jenkins you have the option to `stash` and `unstash` files, sort of like uploading and downloading artifacts that are not visible to the user.
It grants you the ability to do part of the build on one machine, and then continue doing it on another one.

Does this option exists in Teamcity?
I saw the `snapshot dependency` option, but it doesn't seem to transfer any files between builds.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Artifact Dependencies](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Artifact+Dependencies)

The **Build Configuration Settings** | **Dependencies** page, **Artifact Dependencies** section allows configuring the dependencies.  Since TeamCity 10.0, it is possible to disable a configured dependency temporarily or permanently using the corresponding option in the last column of the Artifact Dependencies list.

Comment: That's not quite like `stash` and `unstash` though. When you `stash`, it's not visible to the user.

Comment: it's not visible to the user. also, you can limit the rights for a specific user

Comment: What I mean is, If I upload artifacts, users would see that the build has these artifacts.
I guess the way to go is just upload artifacts to a certain folder, but it's not quite what Jenkins offer.